# Calculate the Intersect Area of Polygon Features and Circles of Equal Area Based on Feature Centroid

Tags: intersection, arcgis-pro

For this task I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.1.  I am trying to fist create a process then automate the process to do the following:

1. Create circular polygons of equal area to and with the same centroid as the polygon features.
2. Determine the intersection of the original features and the new circular polygons.
3. Solve for Bottemma's formula for each feature and write that solution to the original feature class in one field.  Bottema's formula is here:

[image]

I have been able to calculate the centroid of each feature.  Next, I have created buffers using a field which calculates the radius of each buffer based on the area of each feature.  My process begins to break down when I run the intersect tool.  As seen below, the resulting intersect is a multipart feature.  The highlighted polygon represents one of the original polygon features.  Additionally, the buffers often overlap each other which creates problems with the intersections.

[image]

It seems like every feature needs to be run through this process individually in order for this to work.

Are their any built in tools to ArcGIS that might also simplify this process?

Comment: In your intersect select features where polygon I'd <>buffer I'd and delete them. Summarise Results per polygon - overkill - and transfer Results back to polygon.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on your overall process because to do so would involve answering a number of questions along the way, but you say:

> My process begins to break down when I run the intersect tool. As seen
>   below, the resulting intersect is a multipart feature.

You can use the [Multipart To Singlepart](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/multipart-to-singlepart.htm) tool to maintain single part features because it:

> Creates a feature class containing singlepart features generated by
>   separating multipart input features.